# I have difficulties in solving problems in analytic number theory.

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-number-theory

My problem consists of 3 parts. 
Let $\alpha,\beta>0$ and $\alpha\beta=\pi^2$

(1) Let $f(\alpha)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)(e^{(2k+1)\alpha}+1)}+\frac{1}{8}\log\alpha$

Then $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$

(2) $\alpha\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}sech^2{\frac{(2k+1)\alpha}{2}} + \beta\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}sech^2{\frac{(2k+1)\beta}{2}}=1$

(3) $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}sech^2{\frac{(2k+1)\alpha}{2}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$

I solved (2) by differentiating (1) in $\alpha$ and solved (3) by putting in $\alpha=\beta=\pi$.

So the difficult part is (1). I tried to use some identities or telescoping, however it is too hard to use the condition that $\alpha\beta=\pi^2$ in infinite summation and proper identities to use. And I thought about contour integrals of a nice functions such that residues are of the form in (1) but also failed to find such function. Finally by integrating both side of (1) and if I show the equality, then I can prove (1) since we can use the fact that when $\alpha=\beta=\pi$, the initial condition is satisfied.

(2) is the result of (1) so it is not useful to show that the differentiated terms are equal.

Is there any method to prove the identity (1) clearly? Thank you for reading my question.

p.s. I considered to use poisson summation formula, but cannot find such suitable function.

Comment: where does it come from ? what is the context ?

Comment: I do not know the exact context, but maybe it is related to modular functions.

Comment: ok. then see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series#Fourier_series

Comment: Umm.. could you give me a little bit more details?

Comment: you can make $\sigma_{-1}(n) = \sum_{d | n} \frac{1}{d}$ appear in $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \frac{1}{e^{a k}-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-a m k}}{k} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-a n} \sum_{d | n} \frac{1}{d} =  \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-a n}  \sigma_{-1}(n)$, not so different from what you are asking

Comment: @user1952009 I tried to use your comment, however,  I cannot find where the 1/8 $log\alpha$ comes from

Comment: and anyway my idea doesn't work since it would involves $\sum_{(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus (0,0)} (m+n \tau)^{-2K}$ with $K=0$ ... with $K= 1$ it would work to prove what you ask but for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k+1}{e^{(2k+1) \alpha}+1}$. At least it shows a connexion with the functional equation of modular forms.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen similar nice symmetric relations in several papers by Dixit et al.
One of them is

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.1232v1.pdf

You may search arXiv.org for other related papers by him.

All of them have nice relation like $F(\alpha)=F(\beta)$ where $\alpha\beta=1$, or $\pi^2$

Hope the references are useful.